# Openshift rebuilds app on deploy though hot_deploy marker is present

Tags: node.js, openshift

Trying to git push a simple NodeJS app to Openshift with the hot_deploy marker created, my app still rebuilds on every deploy and the whole deploy process takes up approximately 15-18 minutes to finish. I'm sure that the marker created does it's job because every time I push I see these messages in console:

> remote: Not stopping cartridge nodejs because hot deploy is enabled
>
> ...
>
> remote: Not starting cartridge nodejs because hot deploy is enabled

Does anyone know what can be a reason to this? Why does it rebuild everytime?

Comment: Is your application down during that build time?  If not it's working correctly.  It still has to build your project, but it should not take your application down while it's doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment @corey112358

When deploying the app with a hot_deploy marker, the app does not go down while git pushing to the server. For some reason, I thought that the hot deploy feature was supposed to work like nodemon — I mean instantly reload the app on every git push. I guess I was wrong and  the hot deploy feature works as it supposed to at the moment.

Thanks again)